# PHP 5.4 not showing up on localhost after upgrade from php 5.3.15

Tags: php5, upgrade, osx-mountain-lion

I used [this tutorial](http://mac.tutsplus.com/tutorials/server/upgrading-the-native-php-installation-on-os-x-mountain-lion/) and [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58343/php-5-4-installation-on-mountain-lion) to upgrade mountain lion from php 5.3 to 5.4.

Now after sym linking, when I do `php -v`, I get:

```
PHP 5.4.15 (cli) (built: May 29 2013 18:56:58) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

...which is great but when I try to run my apps, I still get php 5.3.15, which was the earlier version.

`which php` gives me `usr/bin/php` - I don't know if that's changed either!?

Is there some apache settings I need to change? How do I start running my apps on php 5.4?

Comment: Have you restarted Apache since creating the symlink?

Comment: yes - several times

Answer (score -1):

Using this script solved my problem: http://php-osx.liip.ch/